# looping through dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I've got a dataframe and I want to say if value is equal or like, then call column "output" a new value.

My code is below

```
df.loc[df['Varname']=='Intercept','Output']='1Base'
df.loc[df['Varname'].str.contains('Xmas|Bank|Easter'),'Output']='3Holidays'
df.loc[df['Varname'].str.contains('BF'),'Output']='9Events'
df.loc[df['Varname'].str.contains(r'(?=.*Brand)(?=.*ME2)'),'Output']='hjhjha'
df.loc[df['Varname'].str.contains(r'(?=.*Trading)(?=.*ME2)'),'Output']='ghghg'
df.loc[df['Varname'].str.contains(r'(?=.*Sky)(?=.*PovRSP)'),'Output']='dfdfdf'
```

Is there a way I can do this in a dictionary and loop?

for example

```
dict={Intercept : 1Base,
     ,'Xmas|Bank|Easter : 3Holiday
```

and so on

and then loop through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your strings into a dict

```
d = {'^Intercept$': '1Base'
    'Xmas|Bank|Easter': '3Holidays'
    'BF': '9Events'
    r'(?=.*Brand)(?=.*ME2)'): 'hjhjha'
    r'(?=.*Trading)(?=.*ME2)'): 'ghghg'
    r'(?=.*Sky)(?=.*PovRSP)'): 'dfdfdf'}
```

an iterate through this

```
for key, value in d.items():
    df.loc[df['Varname'].str.contains(key), 'Output'] = value
```